# dbt to snowflake connections ERROR Profile Not Found

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am ned to dbt and currently trying to set up my first profile to run dbt via snowflake.
During the setup process, I have created my `profiles.yml`

However, when running `dbt debug`
I receive the following message: profiles.yml file `[ERROR not found]`

The path where my profile is: /Users/Kakurebono .dbt/profiles.yml

**What could be the reason behind not finding the profile?**

This is my profile.yml config setup:

```
udemy-learn-dbt:
target: dev
default:
  outputs:

    dev:
      type: snowflake
      account: zpa43768.us-east-1

      #User/password auth
      user: transform_user
      password: xxxx

      role: TRANSFORM_ROLE
      database: analytics
      warehouse: transform_wh
      schema: dbt
      threads: 1
      client_session_keep_alive: False
```

Comment: Shouldn't the path to profile be `/Users/Kakurebono/.dbt/profiles.yml`. You could locate the folder using `dbt debug --config-dir`

Comment: Thanks, @LukaszSzozda! now the profile seems to be confined, however, the project.yml file still seems to be incorrect. 


`Configuration:
  profiles.yml file [OK found and valid]
  dbt_project.yml file [ERROR invalid]`



`Project loading failed for the following reason:
Runtime Error
  at path ['name']: 'udemy-learn-dbt' does not match '^[^\\d\\W]\\w*$'`



`Error encountered in /Users/Kakurebono/Documents/GitHub/udemy-learn-dbt/learn-dbt/dbt_project.yml`

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was the following:

the `Project.yml` can only be named with **underscore** and **lower case letters**
the `Project.yml` file contains `name:` that can be anything and `profile:` that refers to the `Profile.yml` file. Please bear in mind that both files are white space sensitive!

Run `$ dbt compile` once both files are updated and saved then `$ dbt debug`to check whether everything is running correctly.

The config can be tricky. I would recommend for newbies like myself the [Udemy dbt course](https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-dbt-from-scratch/)